# Get data from external url with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I need to get product data (name, price, image..) from an external url (www.kichink.com/product_id) with ajax and jquery.

Is there a gem for that or what is the proper way to do that?

I'm using rails 3.2.13

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/. You'll need to use JSONP.

Comment: The easiest way would be to not use ajax, unless said external url returned jsonp.

Comment: as you are on `rails`, I'm suggesting you to use `Nokogiri` to parse your desire data from external url.

Comment: Thanks guys, I used Nokogiri to parse the html returned by RestClient.